# How comes this Python code's while loop doesn't stop when run?

Tags: python

Please help with this code...

```
number = 1
while number < 13:
  print("{0} squared = {1}".format(number, number*number))
```

I am not sure why the loop doesn't end when run, can anyone help with this?

Comment: Where do you increment number?

Comment: Why should it end? You set `number = 1` and `number` never changes after that,

Comment: Because 1 (*number*) is always smaller than 13.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an infinite loop. A while loop executes until the given condition is true. number is not incremented. So you must increment it each time. Like: `number = number**2`

Answer (score 0):

The 'number' variable is never even changed in that while loop. In order to actually make 'number' change value (I assume you want to square it each time) you'll need something like this:

```
number = 1
while number < 13:
  print("{0} squared = {1}".format(number, number*number))
  number = number * number
  #      ^ This actually changes the value of 'number' in each loop
```

(Also note that if you start from 1 it'll never go up: 1² = 1)

Kinda unclear though what you want to achieve here though. Did you want to:

- Square the previous number to get the new number?
- Show the square value for each number up to 13?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from python 3.8 you can use [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) to modify variable and return new value inline:

```
number = 1.01
while number < 13:
    print("{} squared = {}".format(number, number := number*number))
```

*Btw, starting for `1` is bad idea.*

Answer (score 0):

You can Do this in `Python 3.8`

```py
number = 1
while number < 13:
    print(f"{number} squared = {((number:=number+1)-1)**2}")
```

## output:

```
1 squared = 1
2 squared = 4
3 squared = 9
4 squared = 16
5 squared = 25
6 squared = 36
7 squared = 49
8 squared = 64
9 squared = 81
10 squared = 100
11 squared = 121
12 squared = 144
```

read this : [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean:

```
for number in range(1, 13):
    print("{0} squared = {1}".format(number, number*number))
```

The latest option for formatting strings is to use `f-strings`, so the print line could be:

```
    print(f"{number} squared = {number*number}")
```